# Set focus on onChange event of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to set focus on textbox's itself on-change event if result is wrong. Suppose my textbox id is 'txtCaseCode'.

```
$('#txtCaseCode').change(function() {

     if(condition does not satsfy)
     {
        alert('Wrong ID');
        $('#txtCaseCode').focus();
     }

}
```

Bit it is not working. How will i achieve this?

Here is code after blur event attached:

```
 $('#txtCaseCode').change(function() {
     if(condition does not satsfy)
         {
            alert('Wrong ID');
            $('#txtCaseCode').blur(function(){
            $('#txtCaseCode').focus();//this is not working
            $('#txtCaseCode').val('Please click here.');//this is not working
             });
         }
     else
        {
           execute code;
        }
}
```

Comment: Post full code, If condition is false then never alert display

Comment: you already have the focus on textbox when onchange event fires.

Comment: What kind of element is `'#txtCaseCode'`? Is it `<input type="text"/>` or is it `<textarea>`? or `<div contentEditable="true">`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the event you're attaching to `blur`. This way, whenever the text-box loses focus, you can have the focus returned to it.

The `change` event occurs just before `blur`, and thus, calling `focus()` on a focused event does nothing.

Comment: I tried by attaching blur event after error message. But still its not working.

Comment: @ Mota Chuha: Yes I already have focus on this textbox when page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
 var $txt = $("#txtEmail").focus();

  $txt.blur(function(){   
    if(!validateEmpty(this)){
       $(this).focus();
    }    
 });

function validateEmpty(el){
    var flag = true,
         v = $(el).val();

    if(v == ""){
        alert("Can't Leave Blank");
        flag = false;
    }

   return flag;
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4anAx/2/

I hope It Helps.